# FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: Binary XML file line #81: Binary XML file line #81: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am stuck in this issue when i open the dialog it works fine and when i click on second time it crashes .
Please provide some suggestions to solve this problem . 
Thank you.

This is my xml -

```
                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/map_container"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:background="@color/white" />
```

Here is my java code -

```
                    try {
                        FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

                        SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment
                                = (SupportMapFragment) myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map_container);


                        mySupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(
                                new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mGoogleMap) {
                                        googleMap = mGoogleMap;
                                        AppDelegate.LogT("Google Map ==" + googleMap);
                                        showMap();
                                    }
                                }
                        );
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        AppDelegate.LogE(e);
                    }
```

Comment: Can you add your layout code ?

Comment: Add youre  Xml Code

Comment: Please share your xml code whole tag which is inbetween those 81 line so we can understand easily

Comment: XML code added.

Comment: Add your whole class code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i open the dialog it works fine and when i click on second time
>   it crashes

Because fragment is inflated once the dialog opens. and when you open it second time it inflates it second time which is already inflated. try below code. in this it removes the fragment on dialog dismiss.

Here ,In remove add your fragment object.

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface arg0) {
                // do something
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(SupportMapFragment).commit();


            }
        });
```

Comment: make sure you use this code after dialog and fragment initialization.

Answer (score 2):

or you can just do :

define this

```
   SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment;
```

and inflate it later in class like :

//if it is null than only inflate

```
  if(mSupportMapFragment==null)
   {
      mySupportMapFragmen = (SupportMapFragment) myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map_container);
   }
```